# Google Cloud python autheticated request to cloud run using local application default identity token

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication, google-cloud-run

I am trying to convert the [following](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/developers#console-ui) command from CLI (that works) to python but I am having some problems.

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" SERVICE_URL`

The problem is that I cannot request a valid Bearer with [application default local credentials](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default) token to make authorized request to Google Cloud Run. If I generate Bearer token from CLI `gcloud auth print-identity-token` and use it in a python request all works fine

```py
request_url = 'https://<my endpoint>'
identity_token = '<>' # response of gcloud auth print-identity-token)
header= {'Authorization': f'Bearer {identity_token}'}
requests.get(url=request_url, headers=receiving_service_headers)
```

From google auth [documentation](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html) I understood that Cloud Run communicationis based on Identity Tokens that support Impersonated authentication but I cannot generate valid credential.

```py
from google.auth import impersonated_credentials, default
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession

request_url = 'https://<my endpoint>'
source_credentials, project = default()

creds = impersonated_credentials.IDTokenCredentials(
    source_credentials,
    target_audience=request_url)

authed_session = AuthorizedSession(creds)
resp = authed_session.get(request_url)
print(resp)
```

bui I get following error

```
google.auth.exceptions.GoogleAuthError: Provided Credential must be impersonated_credentials
```

Thanks

Comment: Edit your question with a minimum reproducible example. For example, you are not showing how you are creating credentials (`source_credentials`). Do you actually need to impersonate? What are you impersonating?

Comment: The second snippet of code can be used to reproduce the error. I get local application default creds with `default()` method (after executing `gcloud auth application-default`) rhen I need to get from this creds identity token to make a call on an authorized cloud run endpoint. I don't think I need impersonate but I found this solution as a workaround to use application default credential since `source_credential.id_token` gives unauthorized. If i use `service_account.IDTokenCredentials.from_service_account_file` works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today it's impossible. I talked about it in an [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/the-2-limits-of-iam-service-on-google-cloud-7db213277d9c). You need a service account to generate a valid JWT token with the Google Auth library. It's the same problem with all the library and all the languages.

Last week, I pushed a [merge request in the Java auth library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/pull/469) to solve this. I don't know why Google don't implement it by itself.

On your local environment, if you want to use the same code locally and in the cloud, you have to generate a service account key file and use it with ADC. And it's sadly a security issue...

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the [enter link](https://curl.trillworks.com/) if you want to convert the curl command to python request. Here is converted code:

import requests

headers = {
'Authorization': 'Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)',
}

response = requests.get('http://SERVICE_URL', headers=headers)

Comment: The problem is that `gcloud auth print-identity-token` isn't a plain http request but it's a gcloud cli utility

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53472429/how-to-get-a-gcp-bearer-token-programmatically-with-python/53472880