# How to get a GCP identity-token programmatically with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-iam

What is the python programmatic alternative to the gcloud command line  `gcloud auth print-identity-token`?

I am trying to invoke Google Cloud Function by http trigger (only for auth users) and i need to pass the identity token in the Authentication header. I have method which works great when i run the code on GCP app engine. However, i struggle to find a way to get this identity token when i run the program on my own machine (where i can create the token with gcloud command line  `gcloud auth print-identity-token`)

I found how to create access-token according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53472429/how-to-get-a-gcp-bearer-token-programmatically-with-python/53472880) but i didn't managed to understand how can i create **identity-token**.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great topic! And it's a long long way, and months of tests and discussion with Google.

TL;DR: you can't generate an identity token with your user credential, you need to have a service account (or to impersonate a service) to generate an identity token.

*If you have a service account key file, I can share a piece of code to generate an identity token, but generating and having a service account key file is globally a bad practice.*

---

I released [an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/the-2-limits-of-iam-service-on-google-cloud-7db213277d9c) and 2 merge requests to implement an evolution in the Java Google auth library (I'm more Java developer that python developer even if I also contribute to python OSS project) [here](https://github.com/guillaumeblaquiere/google-auth-library-java/tree/492/IdTokenCredentialFromServiceAccountCredentialAPI) and [here](https://github.com/guillaumeblaquiere/google-auth-library-java/tree/468/idtokenUserCredential). *You can read them if you want to understand what is missing and how works the gcloud command today.*

On the latest merge request, I understood that something is coming from google, internally, but up to now, I didn't see anything...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a service account you can impersonate this is one way to get an ID token in Python from a local/dev machine.

```
import google.auth
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession


def impersonated_id_token():
    credentials, project = google.auth.default(scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
    authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)
    sa_to_impersonate = "<SA_NAME>@<GCP_PROJECT>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    request_body = {"audience": "<SOME_URL>"}
    response = authed_session.post( f'https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/{sa_to_impersonate}:generateIdToken',request_body)
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(impersonated_id_token().json())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the shell command via `subprocess.check_output` from python and use the returned value as well.

This worked for me:

```
gcloud_itoken = subprocess.check_output(["gcloud","auth", "print-identity-token"])
gcloud_itoken_str = gcloud_itoken.decode().strip()
do_something(gcloud_itoken_str)
```

Answer (score -1):

Struggled a bit to find the ideal solution for generating the token programatically, but found it in the official documentation itself eventually.

Sharing the python code snippet from the same

```
import urllib

import google.auth.transport.requests
import google.oauth2.id_token


def make_authorized_get_request(endpoint, audience):
    """
    make_authorized_get_request makes a GET request to the specified HTTP endpoint
    by authenticating with the ID token obtained from the google-auth client library
    using the specified audience value.
    """

    # Cloud Functions uses your function's URL as the `audience` value
    # audience = https://project-region-projectid.cloudfunctions.net/myFunction
    # For Cloud Functions, `endpoint` and `audience` should be equal

    req = urllib.request.Request(endpoint)

    auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, audience)

    req.add_header("Authorization", f"Bearer {id_token}")
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

    return response.read()
```

Here's the [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating?&_ga=2.41628962.-1653748689.1698319834#generating_tokens_programmatically), hope it helps. Worked for me.