# Is API Key enough to access GAE AdminAPI features?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, python-3.8

I'm trying to automate creating Firewall Rules for my Python 3 Google App Engine.  [Per their docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/creating-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules), I can use the Admin API for that (which I've enabled in the Cloud Console).  I've created an [API Key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) too on [the APIs & Keys/Credentials page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) (no restrictions).  The [Python library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/start.md#authentication-and-authorization) implies I can use this key with that library.  However, When I use my `API_KEY` with the below code, I get:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1beta/apps/{my project ID}/firewall/ingressRules?key={my API Key}&alt=json returned "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.". Details: "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.">
```

The URLs in the error are useless because I'm deliberately trying *not* to use Oauth2 (overkill).  Here's the code producing the above error:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


def set_firewall_rules(file_name):
    infile = open(file_name)
    service = build('appengine', 'v1beta', developerKey=API_KEY)
    existing_rules = service.apps().firewall().ingressRules().list(appsId='{my project ID')
    print(existing_rules.execute())
    service.close()
    return
```

Why is my API key insufficient?  Are there settings on my app I need to change, or do I have to make a service account with scopes and all that Oauth2 stuff?

Also, I notice that if if I move my `service.close()` line before my `print` line, I get `AttributeError: 'Http' object has no attribute 'http'`, so it seems I'm at least 2 steps away from success.   It makes using `gcloud` in a bash script the easier way to go...

I'm using Python 3.8 in a virtual env with google-api-python-client 1.12.8.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to use API key when calling `apps.firewall.ingressRules.list`. You need to use OAuth as the method requires the following OAuth Scopes:

- appengine.admin
- cloud-platform
- cloud-platform.read-only

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53472880/7031308) is a good answer with regards to authenticating with service account credentials. To note:

> Notice the scopes parameter. This defines permissions that are granted to the resulting credentials object.

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'service-account-credentials.json'

from google.oauth2 import service_account

cred = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
```

---

As additional reference, here's the REST API:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1beta/apps.firewall.ingressRules/list

Here's the RPC equivalent:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rpc/google.appengine.v1beta#firewall