# How to get Access Token from Google Service Account key file?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication

I am trying to reach my automL model prediction endpoint that I have setup, I have created a service account and added the correct role to it, now I am trying to call the endpoint in Python, but I am not sure how to call it:  Here is what I have tried.  The key file is downloaded from google so it's good.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
project_id = 'aaa'
endpoint_id = 'bbb'
with open('./ServiceAccountKey.json') as source:
    info = json.load(source)
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(info)
scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
access_token = scoped_credentials.get_access_token()
endpoint = f"https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1alpha1/projects/{project_id}/locations/us-central1/endpoints/{endpoint_id}:predict"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token}
payload = {}
x = requests.post(endpoint, data = payload, header=headers)
print(x)
```

The error I get is this:

```
AttributeError: 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'get_access_token'
```

Permissions I have given the service account:

[image]

Comment: 1) `access_token = scoped_credentials.token`. 2) You might need to call `scoped_credentials.refresh()` first. 2) Tip: Use `from_service_account_file()` instead of `from_service_account_info()`. 3) You can add the scopes in a single call instead of multiple calls. `credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('ServiceAccountKey.json', scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use the [AI Platform Python client library](https://googleapis.dev/python/aiplatform/latest/index.html). Set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to the path to your service account file and you are good to go.

Better to not deal with access token and refresh tokens yourself if there is a ready-made library available.

Comment: There may be some cases where setting GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS isn't possible. I provided [the alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53472429/how-to-get-a-gcp-bearer-token-programmatically-with-python/67069710#67069710) in Python3.