# GCP Create Project via Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have an organization under which I want to create a project using python, as per the documentation, without mentioning the parent , service account throws error as below
**"Service accounts cannot create projects without a parent.". Details: "Service accounts cannot create projects without a parent."**

Hence I provided a parent as below,

```
def create_signer(googleservice, principal, key, version):

    google_token_uri = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token'
    if not all(['principal', 'key']):
        raise Exception('Google secret missing principal and/or key')
    signer = crypt.RSASigner.from_string(key.strip())
    credential = service_account.Credentials(signer, principal,
                                             google_token_uri)
    service = build(googleservice, version, credentials=credential,
                    cache_discovery=False)
    return service


def create_project():

    service = create_signer('cloudresourcemanager', principal, key, 'v1')
    operation = service.projects().create(
        body={
            'parent': {'type': 'organization', 'id': '72******78*8'},
            'project_id': 'abcd1234'
        }).execute()
    print(operation)
```

But this throws below error,
**googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects?alt=json returned "The caller does not have permission". Details: "The caller does not have permission">**

I have created a custom role at organization level with below permissions and attached it to my service account created at project level(since organization does not allow creating service accounts at organization level),

```
iam.roles.create
iam.roles.delete
iam.roles.get
iam.roles.list
iam.roles.undelete
iam.roles.update
orgpolicy.constraints.list
orgpolicy.policies.list
orgpolicy.policy.get
resourcemanager.folders.create
resourcemanager.folders.get
resourcemanager.folders.getIamPolicy
resourcemanager.folders.list
resourcemanager.folders.setIamPolicy
resourcemanager.organizations.get
resourcemanager.organizations.getIamPolicy
resourcemanager.organizations.setIamPolicy
resourcemanager.projects.create
resourcemanager.projects.createBillingAssignment
resourcemanager.projects.get
resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy
resourcemanager.projects.list
resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy
```

Can someone please help me with this issue? I have all the required permissions but still having throws 403 error

Just to add, gcp list api call projects works fine

Comment: Have you deleted your Service Account and created it again with the same name? Also do you have an owner role in your Service Account?

Comment: I do not have owner permissions on the project, however I have few more roles added like Organization administrator. Why do I need to delete service account and create again? sorry, I did not get your point

Comment: I was asking have you deleted and recreated SA with the same name by any chance? You can refer this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/multicluster-management/connect/troubleshooting#permissiondenied_errors). Also give owner permission on the project and try again.

Comment: According to the error that you provided in the link it seems like you have authentication problem. Sufficient [scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#cloudresourcemanager) is not added in the api. You need to add scope in your code. Can you try to add 1. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform 2. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only scopes in your code. There is a sample [stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53472880/15745106) which will help you. Try this out and let me know if this solves your issue or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the issue, its not related to permissions but actually the way the permissions are added. i.e. we need to add the permissions in "Setup your Foundation->Administrative Access" for this to work with proper permissions.

Thanks Bakul for your guidance. Here we can provide the service account name and attach roles to it.

Comment: Hello @Prashanth,Glad that your issue got resolved. If you think that my answer helped you in anyway, please consider to upvote it. I'd really appreciate it. Have a great day, thanks!

Comment: Hello @Prashanth. If my solution helped you in any way please consider to upvote the answer. As you have accepted your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to the error that you provided in the link it seems like you have authentication problem. Sufficient [scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#cloudresourcemanager) is not added in the API. You need to add scope in your code.Try to add :

1. **googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform**
2. **googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only**

scopes in your code.

You can refer to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53472880/15745106) case which will help you.