# How to get a GCP Bearer token programmatically with Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-iam

How to get gcloud access token programmatically in Java which we can get from this command `gcloud auth print-access-token`.

Something similar like this [python code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53472429/3182598)

Answer (score 3):

You can do like that

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Sandbox{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
        System.out.println(credentials.getAccessToken());
    }
}
```

with that dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, this has not worked out for us. Instead of getting the token, we get a warning message in the logs: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.

Comment: It does not work? Or is it working + warning message?

Comment: wasn't working; the value came as null. And it would print a warning message. But we solved it, and it's been shared at a few other places too : have to do a refreshToken() in middle. I don't have the exact syntax as its on a colleague's machine.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes across this, @Nikhil VJ's comment led me to something like this that worked:

```java
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.AccessToken;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Example {
  private static void setup() throws IOException {
    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
    credentials.refreshIfExpired();
    System.out.Println(credentials.getAccessToken().getTokenValue());
  }
}
```

the `credentials.refreshIfExpired()` is what I was missing.