# How do I get the current gcloud configuration user/service account's id token in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using gcloud configurations to handle my CLI access. (switching between them with `gcloud config configurations activate <env_name>`). I'm NOT using `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var at all as I want to be able to switch between configurations/projects/accounts.

It works well with resources like `google.cloud.firestore.Client()` which takes the current configuration .

I'm trying to have [authenticated calls](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating?_ga=2.21152633.-390339464.1679569752&_gac=1.222690665.1679569752.Cj0KCQjw8e-gBhD0ARIsAJiDsaVA-1FKsiCWcO-VFu-VhuC4y5I9dWmnIGwPGykK87c7A5YUE8lPXv0aAuyjEALw_wcB#generating_tokens_programmatically) between my (python) cloud functions.
When I try to get the token using -

```py
auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, audience)
```

I'm getting `google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Neither metadata server or valid service account credentials are found.` I'll note that in a real cloud function `fetch_id_token` works.

I am able to get the token using cli command `gcloud auth print-identity-token`, but I want to get it using the python google auth library so it will work on both my local machine (using functions-framework) and in a real cloud function.

Is it possible? am I approaching all of this in a wrong way?

btw I'm using a Linux machine.

Answer (score 3):

I have been struggling with the same issue. For some reason, there is almost no documentation on how to do this, but i managed to find a working way based on the following question [How to get a GCP Bearer token programmatically with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53472429/how-to-get-a-gcp-bearer-token-programmatically-with-python?newreg=dc9e893dd6b84c0fadf287a75b439ff8) that asks for access token. I found that id tokens can be fetched in the same way.

Using the following snippet:

```
import google.auth
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request as GoogleAuthRequest
auth_req = GoogleAuthRequest()

creds, _ = google.auth.default()
creds.refresh(auth_req)

id_token = creds.id_token
```

You will be able to fetch the id_token from local default credentials, following the order established in the documentation https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/reference/google.auth.html

This also works with the metadata server if running on a cloud environment

Comment: Looks like this only works locally, in the cloud environment this gives the `AttributeError: 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'id_token'` error. To have a code that works universally, you should still fallback to `google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, audience)` for Compute Engine, App Engine or Cloud Run.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the proper settings in place and the `google.auth` library can locate the credentials, you can get an ID token for the current `gcloud` configuration in Python. To get the ID token, utilize the audience parameter of the `google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token()` method and set the URL of the Cloud Function you want to use for authentication as the audience parameter.

References:

- [Managing gcloud CLI configurations](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/configurations)
- [Authentication at Google](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication)
- [google-auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [google.oauth2.id_token module](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.id_token.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. As I've mentioned, this works on a cloud function, but not locally. I do have gcloud configuration set up locally, and it works for all cli and even python libs (like `google.cloud.firestore.Client()`) but does not work with `google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token` - I get "Neither metadata server or valid service account credentials are found"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I WAS getting it wrong*, according to the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/use-cases#adc) -

> The recommended way to use Google APIs is to use a client library and
> [Application Default Credentials (ADC)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc).

This works in a local development environment as well.

[ADC searches](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials#search_order) for credentials in the following locations (in this order)

1. GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable
2. User credentials set up by using the Google Cloud CLI
3. The attached service account, returned by the metadata server

When [logging in](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#local-dev) with `gcloud auth application-default login`, this command puts your credentials into a well-known location for use by ADC in a local development environment (e.g. `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`). These are your **local ADC credentials**.
The `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is NOT set automatically and is not needed, in most cases.

The credentials you provide to ADC by using the gcloud CLI (with `gcloud auth application-default login` as mentioned above) are **distinct** from your [*gcloud credentials*](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#gcloud-credentials) — the credentials the gcloud CLI uses to authenticate to Google Cloud (i.e. with `gcloud auth login`, and using [named/topic configurations](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/configurations) using `gcloud config configurations activate <env>`). These are used to authenticate to and authorize access to Google Cloud services.

> Your *local ADC credentials* are not used by the gcloud CLI, and your
> *gcloud credentials* are not used by ADC. They are two distinct sets of
> credentials.

#### Fetching ID token for authenticated requests

Ok, So we had local ADC credentials, and we had gcloud credentials. But neither of them will work with `google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token` locally. For this, you'll need to use credentials of a service-account. you can [get them using the web console or CLI](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/keys-create-delete#creating), in short it's a json file, similar to the one that is created upon logging in with `gcloud auth application-default login`, but of a service-account. In order to make it work, you'll need to direct ADC to use this file - e.g. setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to this json file's path.

---

* In my defense I can confirm that `google.cloud.firestore.Client()` library works very well with *gcloud credentials*, including with different named configurations, which was the thing that really confused me. I'm still not sure why it works, as opposed to others like `google.cloud.storage.Client()`, which only works with *ADC credentials* locally.